# Jenkins how to not trigger build without a specified parameter

Tags: jenkins

I have project in build which triggers downstream project if build is successful. I'm using Jenkins Parameterized Trigger plugin for that. This project is running on two different ip which are passed as parameter to that build. I want to run my downstream project only with one of these ip. How can I do that?

Comment: Are the two ip addresses static?  Will they ever change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have access to the IP address in the upstream job you could use the [Conditional Build Step](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Conditional+BuildStep+Plugin) plugin.

You will select the conditional build step as your build step and set the condition to check if the current ip address is the one you want to run the downstream job on. This part will depend on exactly how you can access the ip address.  It is likely you either have a parameter for the upstream job that specifies the ip address, or you've got it exposed as an environment variable*. Either way you will probably perform a string compare and compare hard coded string with the ip address against the parameter/env. variable value to see if they match.

Then inside the conditional step you'll select the same build step (execute script, trigger builds on other projects, etc.) you are currently using to trigger the downstream build.

---

*If you are using a script to determine the value of the ip address you'll need to inject it into environment of the build to expose it to subsequent build steps.  See the [second half of my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42795037/5220640) on how to do that